# finding a matrix A based on conditions

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

[image: conditions]

Hi!

I am working with a task, and i dont understand how to start to look for a matrix that matches the conditions. The image above has all the details. But my main question is where to start with this?

Hopefully someone can help me with this!

Regards

Comment: Explain how you found it: "I asked math.stackexchange.com".

Comment: Please don’t include important parts of your question as an image. It’s neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor does it show up in summaries of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what do the conditions tell you about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$?  How do you find a matrix with given eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: In task a I know that one of the eigenvalues has to be bigger than the other and that they are real and positive. But how do you include the span of the lines to match? it that the same as the eigenvector?

Comment: Yes: if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$, $x = e^{\lambda t} v$ is a solution that runs along the line spanned by $v$.